# can't find shared_styles_host.ts in Angular version 11+

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

My question is about the file in the @angular/platform-browser because i found a tutorial about implementing CSP in angular and he's talking about a file called shared-styles_host.ts but i only found the same file with the .js extension you can see this link https://dev.to/ferdiesletering/how-to-implement-an-inline-styles-content-security-policy-with-angular-and-nginx-2ke2 and please feel free to contact me to tell me if i am missing something

Comment: i meant in my question the file in the @angular/platform-browser because i found a tutorial about implementing  CSP in angular you can see this link https://dev.to/ferdiesletering/how-to-implement-an-inline-styles-content-security-policy-with-angular-and-nginx-2ke2 and please feel free to contact me  to tell me if i am missing something

Comment: @Audwin Oyong did you find something man

Answer (score 0):

According to your tutorial link, the `_addStylesToHost` function mentioned in it is located in file `platform-browser.d.ts`.

Directory path: `node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\platform-browser.d.ts`

> Before

```
...
private _addStylesToHost; // Add your function here line number 795
...
```

> After

```
private _addStylesToHost(styles: Set<string>, host: Node, styleNodes: Node[]): void {
        styles.forEach((style: string) => {
            const styleEl = this._doc.createElement('style');
            styleEl.textContent = style;
            styleNodes.push(host.appendChild(styleEl));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you i've seen in the tutorial that the file mentioned is called shared_styles_host.ts and the file you mentioned only has some types and declarations in it  @iftikharyk

Comment: Anyway i managed to make the csp work by adding the source that i want beside 'self' source so that any other content that come from a non known source will be blocked